# deep merge with concatenating arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, redux, lodash

I want to deep merge 2 javascript objects with similar properties in a reducer. The catch is the two objects have arrays as their properties and I need them to be concatenated instead of replaced. Basically something like this:

```
var x = {
  name: 'abc',
  family: {
    children: [
      {name: 'xxx'},
      {name: 'zzz'}
    ]
  }
};

var y = {
  name: 'abc',
  family: {
    children: [
      {name: 'yyy'}
    ]
  }
};
```

will result on

```
var y = {
  name: 'abc',
    family: {
      children: [
        {name: 'xxx'}, {name: 'zzz'}, {name: 'yyy'}
      ]
    }
  };
```

any suggestion? I prefer lodash based solution if possible. Also, since it's in reducer, I cannot just replace the property with new object

Comment: what if `x` and `y` objects would have different `name` property value on the parent level?

Comment: in my specific case name can be replaced with source objects

Answer (score 0):

> objects have arrays as their properties and I need them to be
>   concatenated instead of replaced

For your simple example it would be enough to use `Array.prototype.concat()` function:

```js
var x = {name: 'abc', family:{children:[{name: 'xxx'}, {name: 'zzz'} ] }}, y = {name: 'abc', family: {children: [{name: 'yyy'}]}};

y.family.children = y.family.children.concat(x.family.children);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: as I mentioned, I used this in reducer, so I cannot change property in y. I need to replace it with whole object, hence the merge process

Comment: @DanielW, why don't you post that *reducer* ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using lodash, check if [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) doesn't do what you want... (see [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39257322/161622) for example).

Anyway here is a quick function that should do what you want. Be warned that it does very little in terms of checking, and only merges properties that are in the first object (since you said that your objects are similar).

Also it doesn't mutate the objects but instead creates a new one.

```js
function merge(a, b){
  var ret = {};
  for(prop in a){ 
    //assume b doesn't have properties that a hasn't
    //only merge on similar types, else keep a
    var propA = a[prop],
        propB = b[prop];
    console.log(prop, typeof propA)
    if( (typeof propA == typeof propB) && (typeof propA == "object")){
      if(Array.isArray(propA)){
        ret[prop] = propA.concat(propB);
      }else{
        ret[prop] = merge(propA, propB);
      }
    }else{
      ret[prop] = propA;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
var x = {
  name: 'abc',
  family: {
    children: [
      {name: 'xxx'},
      {name: 'zzz'}
    ]
  }
};

var y = {
  name: 'abc',
  family: {
    children: [
      {name: 'yyy'}
    ]
  }
};

console.log(merge(x, y));
console.log(merge(y, x));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume one of your objects is the state you want to change in your reducer.

What about:

```
return Object.assign({}, x, {
   family: [...x.family, ...y.family]
  })
```

First this creates a new empty object and assigns x ( your old state ) to it. Afterwards it assigns the family which it overrides in the new object.
The `...` represents all elements in an array, so this can be used to concat the arrays.